# Is it possible to use TFS 2015 api to QueryHistory changesets from TFS 2010?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-2015

I'm performing a migration of TFS 2010 team projects to TFS 2015 by using the TFS API.  I'm running into an issue when attempting to call `VersionControlServer.GetLatestChangesetId()` and `VersionControlServer.QueryHistory(...)`.

I am using the nuget Team Foundation packages for 2015 to provide dlls.

The exception I am getting is:

```
'VersionControlServer.GetLatestChangesetId()' threw an exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146232000
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    LineNumber: 0
    LinePosition: 0
    Message: "Unexpected end of file."
    Source: "System.Runtime.Serialization"
    SourceUri: null
    StackTrace: "   at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.ReadBOMEncoding(Boolean notOutOfBand)\r\n   at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)\r\n   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.SetInput(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)\r\n   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsSoapMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream)\r\n   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.ReadMessage(HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException webException, Stream responseStream, Boolean& closeResponse)\r\n   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.ReadResponse(HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException webException)\r\n   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.IsAuthenticationChallenge(TfsMessage requestMessage, HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException webException, TfsMessage& responseMessage)\r\n   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendR
equest()\r\n   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)\r\n   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Repository.GetRepositoryProperties()\r\n   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer.GetLatestChangesetId()"
    TargetSite: {SupportedEncoding ReadBOMEncoding(Boolean)}
```

The exception is basically identical for `QueryHistory` and `GetLatestChangesetId`.  From the stacktrace it looks like TFS may be handling encoding differently between from 2010 to 2015.

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to query both the legacy TFS 2010 and our new TFS 2015 via the API.

Comment: You can try to use the TFS2010 dlls and the TFS2015 REST Api https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can use the API to query from TFS2010 and TFS2015, following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace TFSAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string project = "http://xxxxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("username","pwd");
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(project), nc);
            tpc.Authenticate();
            VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            int cid = vcs.GetLatestChangesetId();
            string p = "$/ProjectName";
            var h = vcs.QueryHistory(p,RecursionType.Full,5);
            Console.WriteLine("Following are the latest 5 changeset in " + p +":");
            foreach (Changeset item in h)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.ChangesetId, item.Comment);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The latest changeset ID is:" + cid);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What versions of the TFS SDK DLLs are you using?

Comment: This one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Machado.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using corresponding VS version to work with TFS. With each major release of Visual Studio, we may need to re-build our projects for TFS version control to target the new version of the client object model. What you want is to build your project that references TFS client dlls and supports mixed environments. You can take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/08/12/checkin-policy-multitargeting.aspx for an approach that could work for you.

Hope this helps you.